# php $SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, pathinfo

Here I have .htaccess file with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

And rewriting works but there is no path_info in my index.php when I'm trying http://site.com/example .

I have red this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442854/codeigniter-problem-with-mod-rewrite-on-apache-1-3 but it didn't solve my problem.

So, this issue happens only on apache 1.3 (on 2.0 all is ok) and I wanna know why. I also unfortunately have no access to httpd.conf (

Please, help me.

Comment: If you `var_dump($_SERVER);`, does anything contain what you want? In particular, what does `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contain?

Comment: Yes, there is REQUEST_URI and I build my own path info from it. But I'm just trying to realize other decisions.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L,E=PATH_INFO:/$1]
```

Comment: You just forgot the [colon between `PATH_INFO` and `/$1`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e), of cause it crashes. I will quickly edit it...

Answer (score 1):

This is related to `mod_negotiation` and being able to access `/index.php` as `/index` (without the extension).

Solution:

```
a2dismod negotiation

service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`PATH_INFO`](http://www.google.com/search?q=PATH_INFO) is a virtual path suffix after the real CGI executable / PHP script filename.
You need to pass one to see it:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that you also might require the option to be enabled first: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

And then depending on the PHP SAPI, you might have to configure the php.ini, regarding the `--cgi-force-redirect` setting (which is designed to eschew PATH_INFO exploits for some setups). http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.php

Comment: I tried RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [QSA,L] before, no success. AcceptPathInfo On - this option was added in apache 2 as I know, but my is 1.3 and I cannot upgrade it. If trying to go site.com/index.php/example - path info will appear.